# Row-wise difference between matrix and data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, apply

I have 2 objects: `m1` is a matrix that increases in rows over time, and `m2` is a data frame that decreases in rows over time. Both share common column names (i.e., row, col). What I want is to find the difference between the first row of `m1` and each row of `m2` and have the output stored as an object in a list. This should continue for the subsequent rows of `m1`.

I have tried with `apply(m1, 1, function(x){x - m2})`, but this gives me a result I cannot explain (i.e., the difference doesn't make sense from the second observations onwards). Why is this happenning and what can be done to ensure the difference is returned as desired?

**Data, code and current output:**

```
m1 <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, byrow = T) 
m2 <- data.frame(matrix(1:10, ncol = 2, byrow = T))
colnames(m1) <- colnames(m2) <- c("row", "col")

> m1
     row col
[1,]   1   2
[2,]   3   4
> m2
  row col
1   1   2
2   3   4
3   5   6
4   7   8
5   9  10
> apply(m1, 1, function(x){x - m2})
[[1]]
  row col
1   0   0
2  -1  -3
3  -4  -4
4  -5  -7
5  -8  -8

[[2]]
  row col
1   2   2
2   1  -1
3  -2  -2
4  -3  -5
5  -6  -6
```

**Desired output:**

```
[[1]]
  row col
1   0   0
2  -2  -2
3  -4  -4
4  -6  -6
5  -8  -8

[[2]]
  row col
1   2   2
2   0   0
3  -2  -2
4  -4  -4
5  -6  -6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try the code below

```
apply(
  m1,
  1,
  function(x) {
    t(x - t(m2))
  },
  simplify = FALSE
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
     row col
[1,]   0   0
[2,]  -2  -2
[3,]  -4  -4
[4,]  -6  -6
[5,]  -8  -8

[[2]]
     row col
[1,]   2   2
[2,]   0   0
[3,]  -2  -2
[4,]  -4  -4
[5,]  -6  -6
```

---

Or, another option using `Map` + `split` + `rep`

```
Map(
  `-`,
  split(m1[rep(1:nrow(m1), each = nrow(m2)), ], gl(nrow(m1), nrow(m2))),
  list(m2)
)
```

which gives

```
$`1`
  row col
1   0   0
2  -2  -2
3  -4  -4
4  -6  -6
5  -8  -8

$`2`
  row col
1   2   2
2   0   0
3  -2  -2
4  -4  -4
5  -6  -6
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `sweep`

```
my_function <- function(m1, m2){
  x <- as.vector(m1[1,])
  y <- as.vector(m1[2,])
  m2_1 <- sweep(m2, 2, x, `-`)*-1
  m2_2 <- sweep(m2, 2, y, `-`)*-1
  list(m2_1,m2_2)
}

my_function(m1, m2)
```

```
my_function(m1, m2)
[[1]]
  X1 X2
1  0  0
2 -2 -2
3 -4 -4
4 -6 -6
5 -8 -8

[[2]]
  X1 X2
1  2  2
2  0  0
3 -2 -2
4 -4 -4
5 -6 -6
```